# Update database table from checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

I have a simple checkboxlist which is binded to a database table( with two columns hobbyId and hobbyName).So if i select a few hobbies and hit update,it updates a different table(with 8 columns of 8 hobby names) for a particular userId.But I am not able to even start to write a code for my "Update" button.I searched for a solution and all i get is the code which creates a new record with each hobby to a new row OR all selected items in one column separated by commas.But i want each item to be binded to a column with the same hoobyname.Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my hobby table that i want to UPDATE.

```
 Create table tblInterest
 (
 Id int primary key identity,
 UserId varchar(10),
 Athletics varchar(1) default 0,
 Cycling varchar(1) default 0,
 EquestrianSports varchar(1) default 0,
 MotorSports varchar(1) default 0,
 Marathon varchar(1) default 0,
 Volleyball varchar(1) default 0,
 Tennis varchar(1) default 0,
 Badminton varchar(1) default 0,
 Basketball varchar(1) default 0
 )
```

UserId comes from a label and a new row is generated as soon as new user is generated with default value 0 for all hobbies.

Comment: Your database design is simply wrong. You should drop tblInterest and create a new table with just a user id and a hobby id. this table should have foreign key constraints to the users table and to the hobbies table, and it's primary key should be the combination of it's 2 columns. this way, when you add or remove hobbies from your system, you don't need to change the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You might create two tables to store this info.
Assuming you already have a user table with Id field...

```
tblInterest
tblInterest.interestId
tblInterest.interestName

tblUserInterest
tblUserInterest.interestId
tblUserInterest.userId
```

The first table tblInterest will contain data for Althletics, Cycling, etc stored under the interestName field.

You'll use this table to databind your checkboxlist to produce the list.
To update, on form submission you'll iterate through each of the items in the checkbox list and either issue an add or delete query to the tblUserInterest table (this is called a junction table or crossover table) for the matching userId and interestId respectively.

This code will help you process the results:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw4x4wa(VS.71).aspx

This code will help you databind the checkboxlist and also has code to help you process the results:

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-bind-data-to-checkboxlist-control-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1042.aspx